# React-Native : Unfortunately the app has stopped on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm a newbie in `React-Native` and I'm facing an error like  `Unfortunately the app has stopped`, when I try to access in my app Android. 
This is my logcat :

```
11-26 21:37:47.795  4061  4061 D ReactNative: [CodePush] Loading JS bundle from "assets://index.android.bundle"
11-26 21:37:47.797  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
11-26 21:37:48.075  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
11-26 21:37:48.075  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
11-26 21:37:48.076  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
11-26 21:37:48.269  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
11-26 21:37:48.270  4061  4061 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
11-26 21:37:48.271  4061  4104 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
```

Does anyone have any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**try this:** Go to **android/app/build.gradle** and **replace** these **lines**:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'

**with these:**

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

*Maybe it is a problem with the play store services.*